Least squares minimization of a set $m$ n-dimensional ellipsoidal equations
I have a set of $m$ ellipsoid like equations of the type:
$$f(x_i, .., x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(x_i-p_i)^2}{a_{i}^2}=1$$
I would to find the vector $x_i, .., x_n$ that minimizes the squared sum of residuals of such set of equations:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}(f_m(x_i, .., x_n) - 1)^2$$
I know that I can use a numerical method such as Gauss-Newton, but I am not sure how to avoid local minima.
For a simple 2 dimensional example I can count and identify at most $2m$ local minima, but I can not prove they are all, and I am not sure on how to progress to higher dimensions.
Is there a way to enumerate all possible local minima (or pulling regions) for the n dimensional problem?
I do not care if the problem becomes soon intractable as I would be content already to find a solution up to 5 or 6 dimensions.

Can you please explain what is your objective function? and what is the number of constraints $m$ you have?

@Kroki I edited the question, is it clear now?
